# PubSubClient Complation error - no matching function

Tags: mqtt, esp32, raspberry-pi4, arduino-esp32, lora

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <LoRa.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

const int pin_ss = 5;
const int pin_rst = 14;
const int pin_dio0 = 26;
const char* mqttServer = "192.168.137.216"; // MQTT broker IP or hostname
const int mqttPort = 1883; // MQTT broker port
const char* mqttUser = "pi"; // MQTT username
const char* mqttPassword = "Admin123"; // MQTT password
const char* loraTopic = "Test"; // Topic to subscribe/publish to


void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) 
{
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
  {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

PubSubClient mqttClient(loraTopic, mqttServer, mqttPort, callback, mqttUser, mqttPassword);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // initialize LoRa module
  LoRa.setPins(pin_ss, pin_rst, pin_dio0);
  if (!LoRa.begin(866E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }

  // connect to MQTT broker
  while (!mqttClient.connect("ESP32", mqttUser, mqttPassword)) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to MQTT");
  mqttClient.subscribe(loraTopic);
}

void loop() {
  mqttClient.loop();

  // send message to the topic
  String message = "Hello from ESP32";
  mqttClient.publish(loraTopic, message.c_str());
  delay(1000);
}
```

Compilation error: no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::PubSubClient(const char*&, const char*&, const int&, void (&)(char*, byte*, unsigned int), const char*&, const char*&)

Can someone help me with this?
There is some issue with PubSubClient, I try to change the string into character but still no results

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a version of the PubSubClient constructor that takes a topic as its first argument or the username and password.

https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api#PubSubClient2

```
PubSubClient mqttClient(mqttServer, mqttPort, callback, client);
```

You also appear to be missing code to set up the WiFi connection, which would supply the `client` passed as the final argument.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I won't be using any Wifi library in this setup because ESP32 will be set up in the remote location so I will be using LoRa for the same purpose.

Comment: That won't work, the PubSubClient expects a TCP/IP network to run over

Comment: Ok, so that means I can't establish using MQTT but I just need to stick with LoRa to send data from ESP32 to RPi?

Comment: Possibly, but you can't run MQTT over LoRa in this case

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do with just LoRa.